# pythonのforループ文中でリストを用いた条件分岐を行いたい

Tags: python

pythonのforループ文中でリストを用いた条件分岐を行いたいと考えています。具体的には、

```
li=[2,4,6,9]
for i in range(100):
    if i!=2 and i!=4 and i!=6 and i!=9:
```

上のif文中の「2」「4」「6」「9」の部分をリストliを使って、表現したいです。
上記のような書き方じゃなくても構わないです
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 10):

[not in](http://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) が使えます。

> 演算子 in および not in は、帰属 (membership) を調べます。 x in s の評価は、 x が s
>   の要素であれば真となり、そうでなければ偽となります。 x not in s は x in s の否定 (negation) を返します。

```
i not in li
```

Answer (score 4):

for文内で書くならイテレータのほうがいいですね。

```
for i in (x for x in range(100) if x not in li):
```

または

```
for i in filter(lambda x: x not in li, range(100)):
```

Answer (score 3):

A1

```
li=[2,4,6,9]
for i in range(100):
    if i not in li:
        # ここにやりたいことを実装
```

A2

```
li=[2,4,6,9]
for i in [x for x in range(100) if x not in li]:
    # ここにやりたいことを実装
```